# Problem in iterating sharepoint folder content

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-api

I am trying to access Folder from Document Library using web services in C#.
I am using SiteData's `EnumerateFolder()` method to get sub folders and files. But the method gives me only 3 properties for each entry.

> 1. IsFolder
> 2. Url
> 3. Last modified date

So how can we get 'Modified By' field value.
Or there is another solution for enumerating folders and subfolders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the List API in order to get more properties from your objects.

**[Edit - complete code sample]**

The sample needs to be cleaned up, but should give you what you need

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    Lists lists = new Lists(); //http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

    XmlNode coll = lists.GetListCollection();

    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(coll.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("sp", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
    XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
    XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

    viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified_x0020_By\" />";
    queryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"/>";

    XmlNodeList siteLists = coll.SelectNodes("//sp:List", nsMgr);
    foreach (XmlNode list in siteLists)
    {
        if (list.Attributes["ServerTemplate"].Value != "101") continue; //101=DocLib
        XmlNode listItemCollection = lists.GetListItems(list.Attributes["Name"].Value, string.Empty, query,
                                                        viewFields, "4000",
                                                        queryOptions, null);

        XmlNodeList listItems = listItemCollection.SelectNodes("//z:row", nsMgr);
        foreach (XmlNode listItem in listItems)
        {
            if (listItem.Attributes["ows_FSObjType"] == null) continue;
            if (!listItem.Attributes["ows_FSObjType"].Value.EndsWith("#1")) continue;
            PrintModifiedBy(listItem);
        }
    }
}

private void PrintModifiedBy(XmlNode listItem)
{
    string modifiedBy;
    if (listItem.Attributes["Modified_x0020_By"] != null)
        modifiedBy = listItem.Attributes["ows_Modified_x0020_By"].Value;
    else
        modifiedBy = listItem.Attributes["ows_Editor"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(modifiedBy);
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer with some caml code for the ListService. It's not complete but should get you started.

Comment: Thanks mikael..i will try CAML query. but plz be updated with my question. ;)